# Need help with making a Feyman Diagrams with \feynmandiagram to make triple or more arrows very close to eachother

Tags: luatex, feynman, tikz-feynman

so I've been trying to make the following feyman diagrams: 
[image]

[image]

My code looks like this for the first diagram attempt , so far this is what've got:

```
\begin{figure}[H]
\centering
\feynmandiagram [vertical=b to b1] {
 a [particle=\(\nu_\mu\)] -- [anti fermion] b  -- [charged boson,edge 
label=$Z^0$] b1 [blob] ,
c [particle=\(\nu_\mu\)] -- [ fermion] b,

i4 -- [fermion,edge label=$N$] b1,
b1 -- [fermion,bend left=10,edge label=$Hadrons$] i6,
b1 -- [fermion, bend right=10, edge label = $Hadrons$] i5,
b1 -- [fermion,edge label=$\pi^0$] i7,
};
\caption{\label{fig:firs} DIS}
\end{figure}
```

and this is the ouput I am getting: 
[image]

For the second diagram my code looks like this:

```
\begin{figure}[H]
\centering
\feynmandiagram [nodes=circle, large, horizontal=i2 to d] {
a -- [fermion,edge label=$N$] i2 [dot] -- [anti charged boson,edge 
label=$Z^0$] { b  --  {c1, c2}}, i2 --[double,with arrow=0.5,edge 
label=$\mathcal{R}$] { d --[charged scalar,edge label=$\pi^0$]  d1 , d -- 
d2} ,
};
\end{figure}
```

and i am getting something like this: 
[image]

I need some input on how to produce the first and second diagrams based on the code i already have. Much needed help on this. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even though you tagged your question `lualatex`, I'd like to argue it is easier to manually place the vertices. This also avoids the problems with the arXiv.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{tikz-feynman}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing}
\tikzfeynmanset{compat=1.1.0}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[line width=.7pt]
\begin{feynman}
            \vertex (v1) at (0,0);
            \foreach \X [count=\n]in {-15,-9,-3,3,9,15}
            {\vertex (f\n) at (\X:4);
            \draw (v1)--(f\n);}
            \vertex (f0) at (4,4);
            \vertex  (v0) at (0,3);
            \vertex  (i0) at (-4,4);
            \vertex  (i1) at (-4,-1);
            \diagram*{
             (i0) -- [fermion,momentum={\(p=(E,\vec p)\)},edge label'={\(\ell^\pm\)}] (v0),
            (v0) -- [fermion,momentum={\(p'=(E',\vec p')\)},edge
            label'={\(\ell^\pm\)}] (f0),
             (v0)   -- [boson] (v1),
             (i1) --[fermion,momentum'={\(p=(M,0)\)},edge label={$N$}] (v1)
            };
            \draw[decoration=brace,decorate] ([xshift=3mm,yshift=1mm]f6) -- 
            ([xshift=3mm,yshift=-1mm]f1)
            node[midway,right,xshift=3pt,text width=3cm]
            {Hadrons\\ missing\\ mass $W$};
\end{feynman}
\begin{feynman}[xshift=6.5cm]
            \vertex (a1);
            \vertex[right= 5 cm of a1](a2);
            \vertex[above right=2cm of a1] (b1);
            \vertex[above left=2cm of a2] (b2);
            \vertex[right= 1.2 cm of a1](a3);
            \vertex[left= 1.2 cm of a2](a4);
            \path (b1) -- (a4) coordinate[midway] (h1);
            \path (b2) -- (a3) coordinate[midway] (h2);
            \diagram*{
            (a1) -- [fermion,edge label'={$N$}] (a3),
             (a3)   -- [double,edge label'={$\mathcal{R}$}] (a4),
             (b1) --[charged boson,edge label'={$W^i$}] (h1),
               (h1) -- [boson] (a4),
                (a3) -- [scalar] (h2),
                (h2) -- [charged scalar,edge label'={$\pi$}] (b2),
                (a4) -- [fermion,edge label'={$N'$}] (a2)
            };
            \draw[fill=black] (a4) circle (2pt);
\end{feynman}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Btw how can you include the dot in one by the end of vertex "R" where "N'" begins?

Comment: @spacecatbro I just added it by hand. I find that some parts of the tikz-feyman package are more fragile than I would have hoped.